# Tensorflow Hub Build from Source Failing

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-hub

I'm having a problem with Building TF Hub from Source. Can Anyone please help me out? I've been following the steps as given in https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/tensorflow_hub/pip_package/PIP.md
I've installed bazel 0.24.1.

Error I'm Getting:

```
ERROR: /home/tf_hub/hub/WORKSPACE:17:1: name 'git_repository' is not defined
ERROR: /home/tf_hub/hub/WORKSPACE:40:1: name 'http_archive' is not defined
ERROR: /home/tf_hub/hub/WORKSPACE:47:1: name 'new_http_archive' is not defined
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl': no such package '@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl': no such package '@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.552s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Bazel Version: 0.24.1

Python Version: 3

Tensorflow Version: 2.0.0a

Commands to Reproduce:

```sh
(env)~/tf_hub$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/hub
(env)~/tf_hub$ cd hub && bazel build tensorflow_hub/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Expected Output: No Error. Build Sucessful

Answer (score 0):

Latest Versions of Bazel Doesn't support git_repository (which is still used by tensorflow_hub), so Uninstalling Bazel 0.24.1 and installing Bazel 0.18.1 worked.